# Android: trying to center RelativeLayout within root ScrollView

Tags: android

I would like the ScrollView to fill the entire screen and the Relative layout either centered in the ScrollView with its contents centered or filling the ScrollView and centering its contents. The scrollView is just there in case the app is run on a small screen.

I had achieved the effect with just the RelativeLayout as the root, but when I add the scrollView as a wrapper I can not get it to center, the RelativeLayout is just added to the top. I tried chaning layout_height of the RelativeLayout, but this doesn't work either and just gives me a warning.

The funny thing is it looks fine on the graphical layout within Eclipse.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center" >
....
```

Comment: can you post a picture of how it looks, and maybe even one of what you are aiming for? It is hard to tell what exactly you are seeing and what you are whating.

Comment: Try to put another 'rootview', either `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`, inside the existing RelativeLayout and make the new one android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After MUCH ado, this is what finally worked.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always put the `RelativeLayout` inside a LinearLayout which will allow it to be centered.

The problem you are having is there is no gravity attribute for `ScrollView`, so you need another Layout inside the `ScrollView` that does accept gravity.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:fillViewport="true"
         android:gravity="center" >
      </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: @svenoaks I'm glad that solved your problem. I posted the answer based on the comment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the height and width of both the `ScrollView` and the `RelativeLayout` to `fill_parent`. If this doesn't work, please post your whole xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Put another `rootview`, either `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout,` inside the existing RelativeLayout and add those attributes to the new one.

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: I'm afraid it wasn't quite working like this, my initial comment was premature